# How do I replace multi line's with number range in Notepad++

Tags: json, minecraft, notepad

I am trying to replace multiple lines in N++. I searched all over the internet and I cant really find a definite answer. Maybe someone here can help me.

The problem I am facing is how do I get those numbers to be in a range of 0 to 9? Since there are multiple different varieties of the numbers below. The search mode I have been using is extended since I need to convert multiple lines to only 1 single line.

converting this:

```
"pitch": [
                    0.8,
                    1.2
                ],
```

into this:

```
"pitch": 1.0
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Can you please explain what you mean by "get those numbers"?  Are you trying to replace "pitch": [  #, # ] (where # could be any number) with`"pitch": 1.0`  or will the 1.0 change?  If you are trying to replace any number with another chunk of text/numbers, you want to tag this post for help with regular expressions.

Comment: In the Find section of notepad++ I am trying to figure out how to get the `0.8,1.2` to also be inside of the searching parameters for the numbers 0 to 9, and replacing all of that with a `"pitch": 1.0`

Comment: Do you need this to work only for `"pitch"`, or should it work for any attribute name? What do you mean by "numbers 0 to 9"? Do you mean if the array contains numbers larger  than 9 that no replacement should be made? Please give some examples to clarify what should happen with a variety of input.

Comment: Only for `"pitch"`, But thats not much of the important part I am asking for. The important part is how do I get the find tool to scan from 0 to 9 for the 0.8 and the 1.2. I ask for this to be a range because the 0.8 and the 1.2 can change to a lot of different numbers in the .json and I just want allllllll of the `"pitch"` to be just `"pitch": 1.0`